# solving a problem with map reduce

Tags: ruby, mapreduce

I want to simulate in ruby my implementation of the `map` and `reduce` functions for a system like hadoop to verify that the idea works at least.

I have the following problem. I have two lists of elements:

```
List1
3 - A
4 - B
5 - C
7 - D
8 - F

List2
2 - A
8 - B
6 - C
9 - D
4 - E
```

I need to build a common list that includes the sum of the numbers associated with the alphabets common in the two lists:

```
commonList
5 - A
12 - B
11 - C
16 - D
```

I want to make a ruby script with the `map` and `reduce` operations to solve this problem. I am unsure how to tackle on this problem or what procedure to follow to simulate this in a ruby script.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try by considering the elements given in [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) wikipedia article:

- an input reader - in your case this would probably be a method call on `[key, value]` pair from your input hashes.
- a Map function - you already have keys you should be processing your data by, so your `map` worker would just return the `[key, value]` pair it got as an input
- a partition function - a method which would assign a reduce worker based on the key. In your case it could be simply `key.hash % REDUCER_COUNT`.
- a compare function - I don't think this is applicable in your case as you don't need values to be processed in any particular order.
- a Reduce function - would be given `[key, list]` pair, list being list of values associated with the key. It would return the sum of `list` if list is more than one element long (as you want only elements appearing in both input hashes processed).
- an output writer - could be plain Hash in your example.

And [here's](https://github.com/jablan/collectinject) my (over)simplified implementation of the above.

Comment: I am trying your solution, but I am getting an error with this line:
[key, list.inject(&:+)]. I get this error: "TypeError: wrong argument type Symbol (expected Proc)"

Comment: You are probably using older Ruby. Use `list.inject{|acc,i| acc+i}` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Using irb (ruby-1.9.2-p180):

```
list = [ {a:2, b:1, d:3}, {a:3, b:2, c:3}, {a:4, b:1, c:3} ]
 => [{:a=>2, :b=>1, :d=>3}, {:a=>3, :b=>2, :c=>3}, {:a=>4, :b=>1, :c=>3}] 

Hash[list.map(&:keys).inject(&:&).map{|key| [key,list.map{|arr| arr[key]}.inject(&:+)]}]
 => {:a=>9, :b=>4}
```

this solution works with multiple arrays (2+) it finds common keys and sums them returning a hash of results

to find common keys (gather keys and find common part):

```
list.map(&:keys).inject(&:&)
```

to find sum for key (select values by keys and sum them):

```
list.map{|arr| arr[key]}.inject(&:+)
```

to build Hash from array of pairs `[[:a,9], [:b,4]]`:

```
results = [[:a,9], [:b,4]]
Hash[ results ]
```

I love ruby for this one liners!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that we have all the other map-reduce-related functions implemented (input reader, output writer, global sort, ...), these would be the `map` and `reduce` ones:

```
def map(input)
  input.each do |count, letter|
    yield [letter, count]
  end
end

def reduce(letter, partial_counts)
  result = if partial_counts.size == 2
    partial_counts[0] + partial_counts[1]
  end

  yield result
end
```

The `map` function will `yield` a pair `(letter, count)`, which will be grouped later. Then for each `letter` received from `map`s `reduce`will receive an array containing every count yielded by a `map` for that `letter`. As you wish to only yield if the letter occurs on both hashes, we need `count`s to appear on `partial_counts` twice to use it to compute the sum at the end. The `reduce` function could be implemented in several ways. I've tried to make it as simples as possible to understand, although it's implementation is very adjusted to this problem.

Using these `map` and `reduce` implementation will return the last hash with keys and value inverted, which makes more sense, as there may be several letter with the same count. The input would be better if it inverted keys and values too. This way, `map` would be as simple as yielding each pair of `(letter, count)`:

```
def map(input)
  input.each do |letter, count|
    yield [letter, count]
  end
end
```

or

```
def map(input)
  input.each do |i|
    yield i
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list_1 = ["3 - A", "4 - B", "5 - C", "7 - D", "8 - F"]

list_2 = ["2 - A", "8 - B", "6 - C", "9 - D", "4 - E"]

(list_1 + list_2).map do |str|
  # change array of strings to array in the form of [[name, value], ...]
  str  =~ /(\d+) - (.*)/ && [$2, $1.to_i]
end.reduce({}) do |memo, obj|
  # use a temporary Hash to sum up the values;
  # the value is an array in the form of [value_counter, iteration_counter]
  prev = memo[obj.first] || [0, 0]
  memo[obj.first] = [prev.first + obj.last, prev.last + 1]
  memo
end.map do |key, value|
  # convert to array in original format or
  # nil, if occurred only once
  value.last > 1 ? "#{key} - #{value.first}" : nil
end.compact

=> ["A - 5", "B - 12", "C - 11", "D - 16"]
```

This code uses the `map` and `reduce` methods of Ruby, but doing all this directly on a Hash would be much more elegant.